# Impact of Javascript libraries on server side memory

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, kendo-ui

I have an ASP.Net MVC5 project running on IIS7 where I noticed a high (like 2 to 5 times as high) memory use as soon as I added an external javascript library. The app consumes about 100mb's of memory under normal circumstances, once the js is added it consumes 400 to 700 mb of memory on the server.

I understand that using heavy js libs can have an impact on the client, but why and how can it cause such an impact on my server-memory?

For reference, the library was kendo ui.